# pytest.raises() doesn't catch custom exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

It seems that pytest.raises(CustomException) is failing, when the class raises it:

I have a project folder like this:

```
root:
    pytest.ini
    models:
        my_model.py
        custom_exceptions.py
    test:
        test_one.py
```

my_model.py:

```py
from custom_exceptions import MyException

class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.raisers()

    def raisers(self):
        raise MyException
```

test_one.py:

```py
import pytest
from models import my_model
from models import custom_exceptions

class TestOne:
    def test(self):
        assert True

    def test_ex(self):
        with pytest.raises(custom_exceptions.MyException):
            my_model.MyModel("a")
```

custom_exceptions.py:

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

and pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
minversion = 7.0
pythonpath = models
testpaths = test
```

This is under a pyenv venv.  when i run `python -m pytest`, the first test succeeds, but the second one fails:

```
self = <test_one.TestOne object at 0x7fa1f2504b50>

    def test_ex(self):
        with pytest.raises(custom_exceptions.MyException):
>           my_model.MyModel("a")

test/test_one.py:11:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
models/my_model.py:6: in __init__
    self.raisers()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <models.my_model.MyModel object at 0x7fa1f2504790>

    def raisers(self):
>       raise MyException
E       custom_exceptions.MyException

models/my_model.py:9: MyException
========== short test summary info ============
FAILED test/test_one.py::TestOne::test_ex - custom_exceptions.MyException
```

However, this succeeds:

```py
    def test_two(self):
        with pytest.raises(custom_exceptions.MyException):
            raise custom_exceptions.MyException
```

I don't understand what is going on?

I have tried

```py
    def test_ex(self):
        with pytest.raises(custom_exceptions.MyException):
            try:
                my_model.MyModel("a")
            except Exception as e:
                print(type(e))
                print(type(custom_exceptions.MyException))
                raise e
```

And the types are:

```
<class 'custom_exceptions.MyException'>
<class 'type'>
```

Why would the type be 'type'?

Comment: For the last part, `MyException` is a class object. `MyException()` is an instance of `MyException`. `type(MyException)` is `type`, while `type(MyException())` is `MyException`

Comment: Thank you, could it be related to the pytest.raises failing?

Comment: The fact you're importing `custom_exceptions` as both `from custom_exceptions import ...` and `from models import custom_exceptions` is very suspect. It looks like your Python path is goofed such that both `./root` and `./root/models` are on the Python path. That may be a problem, since you end up with two different copies of `custom_exceptions`: a top level `custom_exceptions` and a `models.custom_exceptions`. The `MyException` classes defined in each one will be different classes, which may be why mixing them is not working for you.

Comment: `custom_exceptions` is on the same folder as `my_model.py`  but pytest is on a different folder `test` so it gets imported differently.  Would you advice moving the Exceptions file to the root folder?

Comment: What folder those files are in does not matter per-se. All that really matters is what the Python import path is. If you place `root/models` on the Python path, then you'll be able to import `custom_exceptions` as `import custom_exceptions` from anywhere. Alternatively, if you want `models` to be the top-level package, you can put its containing folder on the Python path, and then use `models.custom_exceptions` everywhere. See also [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165)

Comment: There are a number of different ways you can manage putting the directories you want on the Python path, but the most common are a) relying on it being your CWD, or b) configuring it in your IDE (e.g. marking the folder as "src" in PyCharm), or c) installing your project as a distribution package.

Comment: This needs to be deployed, and the tests must be run as part of a pipeline.  Could perhaps move the Exceptions to it's own folder, or use DistUtils/SetupTools to install them as package to the venv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to sort this issue by changing the project structure:

```
root:
    pytest.ini
    models:
        __init__.py
        my_model.py
    custom_exceptions:
         __init__.py
         custom_exceptions.py
    test:
        __init__.py
        test_one.py
```

and import the customs exceptions like this:
`from custom_exceptions.custom_exceptions import MyException` on both `models/my_models.py` and `test/test_one.py`.

As mentioned in the comments above, the names where different as both import statements where different.  Moving the exceptions file into it's own package solved the issue.

Comment: I really didn't think this refactor would work.  The office heard an audible "WHAT" when all tests passed.